# Skype calls: "cant access your sound card"

Tags: windows-7, skype, sound-card

I have Lenovo with Windows 7, my speakers and microphone working fine, but when I use Skype I have announcement "can't access your sound card" the camera works fine. I did check the settings and I read all the instruction on Skype.com and everything is good, but I can't make calls.

I did "test call" with Skype and most of the time it works.

What is the problem?

Comment: See also [Microphone Privacy Settings](https://superuser.com/a/1291986/350929), worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Run System Update, and make sure all of your drivers are up to date (especially the Conexant audio driver). There was a fix in one of the versions.