# Microphone not working on Windows 10 Version 1803

Tags: windows-10, microphone, windows-10-v1803

When I upgraded to the latest Windows 10 Version 1803 Insider Preview update, my mic stopped working. I posted an answer that fixed my problem and may help others!

Comment: First of all, Welcome to Super User!  We always appreciate the contributions from our community members, but your question probably requires some clarification.  When you emphasize that you *"upgraded to the latest Windows 10 update,"* it's important to note that OS build 17083 is actually the latest [Windows 10 Insider Preview Build for Version 1803](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2018/01/24/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-17083-for-pc/#qtIiqESztLE5wJbg.97), not a mainstream release.  To avoid confusion, we probably shouldn't label it as the latest Windows 10 update.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's a microphone privacy options page. The latest insider's update has it blocking all apps by default.

1. Hit Windows key and search for "microphone privacy settings"
2. Hit "Allow access to the microphone on this device"
3. Switch "Allow apps to access your microphone" to `on`

Comment: This setting always existed

Comment: As @Ramhound said, those setting were already there. More to the point, it sounds like the following article can explain the root cause of your problem: [Announcing Windows 10 Insider Preview Build 17083 for PC](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2018/01/24/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-17083-for-pc/#IvUSyyFtSY8jVf39.97). Within that article, they stated the following: *"We fixed an issue resulting in microphone and camera settings in Privacy settings flipped to deny all device access after upgrading to recent builds."* So, you encountered a Beta problem that they fixed.

Comment: Damn, my work laptops Microphone privacy is set off by GPO.

Comment: Fixed 'Skype "can't access sound card" for microphone', thanks a lot !
Too bad they did not improve the troubleshooter with this setting.

Comment: My BT headset mic didn't work. So I googled for "windows 1803 bluetooth issues" etc., and I found scores of people having BT problems with this build. When in fact in my case it was this very issue, that I found by googling "windows 1803 no microphone". Not just a terrible upgrade behavior from MS, but also absolute failure to communicate (on their own support forums, to start with). Thanks for your answer.

Comment: This works, I had to disable the microphone and re-enable it to make it work. (under sound settings -> recording)

Answer (score 6):

In addition to

- Go to `Settings` > `Privacy` > `Microphone` (left column)
- Make sure "Microphone access for this device is **`on`**"
- And switch "Allow access to the microphone on this device" to **`on`**

as [Ermish's suggested](https://superuser.com/a/1291986/893419), I had to

- disable and enable one of my microphones for the changes to apply apply.

Then all my microphones worked again.

Comment: @Run5k I re-wrote it as a full answer now

Answer (score 3):

I've found the solution [here](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/05/01/all-the-issues-of-windows-10-version-1803-you-may-run-into/):

> "Microphone not detected anymore? Sound settings or features not working? Check Settings > Privacy Microphone and test if "Let apps use my microphone" resolves the issue."

Answer (score 2):

Similar Issue, different cause here

**device**: soundblaster e3, using usb audio

**system**: desktop(Creative SoundBlaster driver installed.) and laptop (Windows 10 auto installed drivers)

**windows**: 1803 clean install, with and without Creative SoundBlaster driver.

**issue**: no mic sound, no meter movement in `control_panel` > `sound`, but sound comes through along with sound meter movement when `Microphone Properties` > `Listen` > "`listen to this device`" is checked.

**solution**: switching default device to another device then back